# wxPython: Drawing a vector-based image from file

Tags: python, wxpython, vector-graphics

How can I draw a vector-based image from a file in wxPython? I know nothing of image formats for such a thing, so please recommend.

Comment: Added python tag, so that it's highlighted for people like me who set “python” as interesting but not “wxpython”.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with using cairo & librsvg python bindings. There is a small example [here](http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2007-April/013778.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar, I had a custom vector image format that I needed to render in a wxPython window.  In order to accomplish this I used the GDI interface for drawing commands and I wrote my own parser module. There is a great GDI tutorial at this site that should help you out: http://www.zetcode.com/wxpython/gdi/